# Christmas card to boyfriend's mum

Tags: grammaire, sens

Qu’est-ce que vous faites ?

C'est ma première fois à envoyer une carte pour vous，Merci beaucoup pour ...

Je garde de bons souvenirs à Bordeaux.

Nous vous souhaitons de joyeuses fêtes de Noël et une excellente année 2018.

c'est santé

Ning

---

1. how to say thanks for your kind in french(cuz i spend one week in her place)
2. Is this kind of polite?
   is it right or not

merci beaucoup ^^

Answer (score 1):

- Qu’est-ce que vous faites ? => What are you doing ?
  I guess you meant *Comment allez vous ?*
- *C'est la première fois que je vous envoie une carte* would be more correct but makes wonder what you mean...
- *Merci beaucoup pour votre gentillesse / pour la gentillesse avec laquelle vous m'avez reçu(e)* (*e* if you're a girl)
- The sentence about christmas is correct, even though it's quite early [**edit** : ...or not, as told me Luke, since it's for Xmas, what I didn't notice]... Note that it means "we wish", not "I wish"
- *c'est santé* : doesn't mean anything ;)

Thanks to automatic translators :)

Comment: Being that the card will be sent at Christmas, I doubt that « Joyeuses fêtes » will be early :p

Comment: oh yes, didn't notice the title :)

Comment: Merci beaucoup Luke and Emmanuel  ^^

Comment: You didn't address "Je garde de bons souvenirs à Bordeaux" and I was wondering if that could also be "DE Bordeaux" depending on what s/he means? Re "c'est santé, that certainly doesn't mean anything! Maybe s/he was trying for something like "Bonne année, bonne santé" cc: @Ning

Comment: You're right, "Je garde de bons souvenirs à Bordeaux" would mean he is in Bordeaux with his memories, while "Je garde de bons souvenirs de Bordeaux" means he is... wherever and has good memories _about_ his stay in Bordeaux. For "c'est santé" I don't know, you might be right, I thought of a bad traduction of _cheers_...

Comment: to Papa Poule  i want to say i have good memories been to her place in boedeaux, i spend one week visited here, the older lady is my boyfriens mum, i want to thanks for her so friendly and take care everything , in chinese we use to say wish you good health,but i think its weird in france maybe?

Comment: to Emmanuel BRUNO  C'est cool !  That's why i need to started early..my poor french ... Merci

Comment: Like said  Papa Poule, you can say  _bonne année et bonne santé_